# Bottom right align a table

Tags: tables, align

[image: The place where i want my text]

I tried with textpos and tabular but it doesn't make really good thing

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,draft]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
...

    \vspace*{\fill}

    %\begin{flushright}

        \begin{tabular}{ |b|b{6cm}|b| }%[b]
            \hline
            \includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{.png} &
            %\begin{textblock}{10cm}%(10cm,6cm)
            text &
            %\end{textblock}
            \includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{.jpeg} \\%[1.5cm]
            \hline
        \end{tabular}

    %\end{flushright}

\end{document}
```

Some ideas ?

Comment: What is the `b` column type (as opposed to `b{6cm}`)?

Comment: I read that b can make the content go on the bottom of the cell (but my code don't work at all, if you have an other idea to make what i show on the draw it will be better)

Comment: As far as I know it has to be `b{some length}` (same as `p` and `m`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change the definition for your table (I deleted all vertical and horizontal lines, because with lines it looks ugly imho):

```
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}cp{6cm}c@{}}
```

With `[b]` we get the table placed bottom, with `@{}` we get rid of the space before or after the images and `cp{6cm}c` centeres the images and placed the text in a box with 6cm width. You can load package `array` and try `m{6cm}` instead `p{6cm}`.

Please see the following mwe (code changings marked with `<=====`):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{array}


\begin{document}
\blindtext

\vspace*{\fill}
%\vfill

\hfill
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}cp{6cm}c@{}} % <==================================
% \hline
    \includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image-a} % <=================
  & text 
  & \includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image-b} \\%[1.5cm]
% \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Based on your comments see the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
\blindtext

\vspace*{\fill}
%\vfill

\hfill
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}} % <=========================================
  \includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image-a} % <===================
\end{tabular}
\begin{minipage}[b]{6cm}
  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{minipage}
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}} % <==================================
  \includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image-b} \\%[1.5cm]
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: pdf 2]

Comment: I use "showframe" "\hline" and "|" to see what i do, but my final document willn't have any lines

Comment: For me your code render exactly like that https://imgur.com/a/k4WW759

Comment: There's gap in cell and between table and margins

Comment: I tested individually your code and and it seems fine as is, but as i add 3 line of text in the "text" cell, the pictures goes up the text and leaves the bottom

Comment: I tried with 3 different tables and it seems to be finer, but it's really drafty

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{array}


\begin{document}
\blindtext

\vspace*{\fill}
%\vfill

\hfill
\begin{tabular}[hb]{|c|} % <==================================
 \hline

    \includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image-a} \\ % <=================
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[hb]{|p{8cm}|} % <==================================

Comment: \hline
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[hb]{|c} % <==================================
\hline
   \includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image-b} \\%[1.5cm]
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @wxi we do not like "living" questions here but see my updated answer. Please next time prepare your question showing exactly your issue, in your case not only `text ` in your table but the real length of your needed text. That makes it easier for us to help and avoids never ending changed questions no other reader can easy follow  ...